# How to add an item of different type to List inside dynamic Map in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say I have a map:

```dart
Map map1 = {'a': ['x']};
```

When I try to add `int` item to list inside map -

```dart
map1['a'].insert(1, 77);
```

Error thrown:

```
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'element'
```

How can I resolve this?

Interesting that if same map was generated from `JSON` - above operation will succeed:

```dart
String json = '{"a": ["x"]}';
Map map2 = jsonDecode(json);

map2['a'].insert(1, 77);

// {a: [x, 77]}
```

EDIT: 
Defining strict type of map (reaching the type of List) not an option because it could be long nested map and its structure may vary. Also the type would be long and unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dart assumes that the inner array is of type `List<String>`. therefor you should specify that the type is dynamic:

```
Map<String, List<dynamic>> map1 = {'a': ['x']};
```

or

```
Map map1 = {'a': <dynamic>['x']};
```

Comment: This simple map was an example. Assume you have long nested map like `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': ['x']}}}}`. Then defining strict type will be messy.

Comment: @AlexKalmikov you can also do `Map map1 = {'a': <dynamic>['x']};` i dont really know a simpler way to do it.